# Symfony 4 - Wrong assets path with Webpack Encore

Tags: symfony, webpack, symfony4, webpack-encore

I have a problem using Webpack Encore.
The path generated by using the `{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}` line in my **base.html.twig** file is wrong.

Instead of getting the following source (which is functional) : `src="./build/app.js"`
I get this one: `src="/build/app.js"` which leads to a 404 error.

This is true for my script as well as for my css.

**Here is my code :**

```
// base.html.twig

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        {# Run `composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle`
           and uncomment the following Encore helpers to start using Symfony UX #}
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block javascripts %}
            {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

```
// webpack.config.js

[...]

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    .copyFiles({from: './assets/img'})
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')

[...]
```

And here is my project hierarchy :
[assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdmUz.jpg)
[build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEJmc.jpg)

Can someone help me with this issue ? I'm sure it's an easy one but I tried to follow the Webpack documentation and it didn't worked as intended.

Comment: You may have a problem in your nginx or apache configuration. The source `src="/build/app.js"` is correct as your root path is supposed to point to `public` folder.
You can have a look to [Symfony docs - Configuring a Web Server](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) to check if your static files (js, css, images ...) can be directly served.